# How to use custom exception from cakephp plugin?

Tags: php, cakephp, plugins

I have some custom exception for my application. I placed them to app where it is running well. Now I want to move them to one of my plugin and use exception from their.

I have implemented custom exception as mentioned here:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/exceptions.html

But, I am looking for same solution if I use exception classes from cakephp plugin.

Any suggestion...???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets say you want to put your exceptions in Custom plugin /app/Plugin/Custom/Lib folder:

```
// Location: /app/Plugin/Custom/Lib/CustomException.php
<?php
class CustomException extends CakeException {};
```

Now you need to load Custom plugin in /app/Config/bootstrap.php:

```
// Location: /app/Config/bootstrap.php
CakePlugin::load('Custom');
```

And wherever you want to use `CustomException`:

```
<?php
App::uses('CustomException', 'Custom.Lib');

class ApiController extends AppController {   

    public function demo() {
        throw new CustomException("Just testing");
    }

}
```